# Is $\mathbb{Z}$ nowhere dense in $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}_{discrete})$?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, metric-spaces

The following definition of nowhere dense is from Introduction to Topology by Theodore W. Gamelin & Robert Everist Greene:

> **Definition.** A subset $Y$ of metric space $X$ is nowhere dense if $\bar{Y}$ has no interior points, that is, if $int(\bar{Y})=\emptyset$.

In usual, if $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with Euclidean metric giving a usual topology, then $\mathbb{Z}$ is nowhere dense in $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}_{E})$. However, if $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with discrete metric, then it gives a discrete topology in $\mathbb{R}$. By definition of discrete topology, every single point is an open set so $\mathbb{Z}$ is an open set. Therefore, $int(\bar{\mathbb{Z}})=\mathbb{Z}\neq\emptyset$, $\mathbb{Z}$ is **NOT** nowhere dense in $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}_{d})$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: Yes, fine, It's enough to note that in this space, *every* set is clopen.